# How to install Yahoo Messenger on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, empathy, pidgin, instant-messaging, yahoo

I'm from India and I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my machine since last year and a half.

So, my issue is: How should I install Yahoo Messenger on my machine?

Installing Yahoo Messenger on Windows machine is just a job of making few clicks and it's ready to use with full set of features. Whereas installing Yahoo Messenger on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is nothing less than a nightmare for me. I tried almost everything from Google search to almost everything to install Yahoo Messenger on my machine but I failed everytime.

After running a search on Google I came to know about Pidgin and Empathy. But neither I found how to use/install Pidgin and Empathy or similar software on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS nor did I find out how to configure Yahoo Messenger with these applications.

The questions asked regarding Yahoo Messenger are quite old, so I'm asking this question in current era to find out if there is any easy way invented to install the Yahoo Messenger on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS like one might install it on any Windows machine?

Comment: You need to add your Yahoo account on online account settings.

Comment: Personally I suggest you install Pidgin or Kopete. The official Yahoo messenger client for Linux is old and outdated.

Comment: Or if you want that follow this [link](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22091)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install `pidgin`, first open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for `pidgin`. Then click install. To run pidgin, just open the Dash (Canonical icon in the top left) and search of `pidgin` and click the icon.

Once `pidgin` is open, it will likely prompt you to add an account. If it does not, go to the Accounts menu and click on Manage Accounts. Then click the Add... button to add a new account.

For Protocol choose Yahoo. Enter your username and password in the Username and Password boxes. Then click Add to add the account. Click Close to close the Accounts window. The Buddy List window from pidgin should now log in to your Yahoo account and let you chat as normal.

Your other option is to use PlayOnLinux to try and install the official Yahoo Messenger installer. However, this is unlikely to work, so I won't describe the process here. It crashed when I tried it on Ubuntu 14.04.